# Removing the Activity from multiple Activity Feeds

Tags: python, getstream-io

I am publishing the activity in the getstream and using "to" to copy the activity in different feeds.

code Snippet to add the activity

```
self.client = stream.connect(settings.STREAM_API_KEY, settings.STREAM_API_SECRET)
user_id = 1
content_id = 5
user_feed = self.client.feed('user', user_id)
to_stream = ["tag:4", "tag:5"]
activity = {
   'actor': user_id,
   'verb': "post",
   'object': content_id,
   'foreign_id': content_id,
   'to': to_stream
}
user_feed.add_activity(activity)
```

code Snippet to remove the activity

```
user_feed.remove_activity(foreign_id=content_id)
```

Once I am removing the activity by above code then its removing the activity from "user:1" but not removing the feeds "tag:4" and "tag:5".

Is there any other way to remove the feeds at once from "user:1" and "tag:4" and "tag:5".

Answer (score 1):

Removing items from feeds can take a few moments. In my test script (which I based on your code above) I used a one-second sleep between the `remove_activity()` call and a `.get()` call on all three feeds and they all came back empty.

```
import stream
import time

STREAM_API_KEY='foo'
STREAM_API_SECRET='bar'

def print_feeds(f1,f2,f3):
    print 'f1'
    print f1.get()
    print 'f2'
    print f2.get()
    print 'f3'
    print f3.get()

client = stream.connect(STREAM_API_KEY, STREAM_API_SECRET)

user_id = 1
content_id = 5

user_feed = client.feed('user', user_id)
tag4 = client.feed('tag', 4)
tag5 = client.feed('tag', 5)

to_stream = ["tag:4", "tag:5"]
activity = { 'actor': user_id, 'verb': "post", 'object': content_id, 'foreign_id': content_id, 'to': to_stream }

user_feed.add_activity(activity)
time.sleep(1)

print '*** after adding to feed ***'
print_feeds(user_feed, tag4, tag5)

user_feed.remove_activity(foreign_id=content_id)

time.sleep(1)

print '*** after deleting from feed ***'
print_feeds(user_feed, tag4, tag5)
```

And this is the output I get:

```
*** after adding to feed ***
f1 (user feed)
{u'duration': u'22ms', u'results': [{u'origin': None, u'target': None, u'object': u'5', u'actor': u'1', u'to': [u'tag:4', u'tag:5'], u'verb': u'post', u'time': datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 30, 18, 40, 2, 556596), u'foreign_id': u'5', u'id': u'64589b08-4567-11e7-8080-8001531a35e4'}], u'next': u''}
f2 (tag 4)
{u'duration': u'16ms', u'results': [{u'origin': None, u'target': None, u'object': u'5', u'actor': u'1', u'to': [u'tag:4', u'tag:5'], u'verb': u'post', u'time': datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 30, 18, 40, 2, 556596), u'foreign_id': u'5', u'id': u'64589b08-4567-11e7-8080-8001531a35e4'}], u'next': u''}
f3 (tag 5)
{u'duration': u'25ms', u'results': [{u'origin': None, u'target': None, u'object': u'5', u'actor': u'1', u'to': [u'tag:4', u'tag:5'], u'verb': u'post', u'time': datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 30, 18, 40, 2, 556596), u'foreign_id': u'5', u'id': u'64589b08-4567-11e7-8080-8001531a35e4'}], u'next': u''}

*** after deleting from feed ***
f1 (user feed)
{u'duration': u'17ms', u'results': [], u'next': u''}
f2 (tag 4)
{u'duration': u'11ms', u'results': [], u'next': u''}
f3 (tag 5)
{u'duration': u'14ms', u'results': [], u'next': u''}
```

Comment: Hello @iandouglas. The Only difference comes here. you are doing user_feed = client.feed('user', user_id) tag4 = client.feed('tag', 4)
tag5 = client.feed('tag', 5)

Comment: tag4 = client.feed('tag', 4)
tag5 = client.feed('tag', 5)
to_stream = ["tag:4", "tag:5"]
activity = { 'actor': user_id, 'verb': "post", 'object': content_id, 'foreign_id': content_id, 'to': to_stream } and we are not initializing the feeds with these two lines tag4 = client.feed('tag', 4)
tag5 = client.feed('tag', 5). We are just making the to_stream = ["tag:4", "tag:5"] and adding the activity. Is this is mandatory to add the feeds by doing tag4 = client.feed('tag', 4)
tag5 = client.feed('tag', 5) and then make the to_stream list?

Comment: no it's not mandatory to do this at all, I only instantiated those feeds so that I could fetch them individually to see they were empty.

Comment: I just confirmed by changing `tag:4` and `tag:5` to be `tag:abc` and `tag:def` in all cases, and also moved the instantiation UNDER the `.addActivity()` call that it had zero impact and am still unable to reproduce your problem.